# Malloc with a structure containing variably sized objects

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I'm trying to create a structure which contains information from each line in a file, so the size of the structure is dependent on the length of the file. C doesn't like me doing,

```
int makeStruct(int x){

    typedef struct
    {
        int a[x], b[x]; 
        char c[x], d[x]; 
        char string[100][x];     
    } agentInfo;

    return 0;
}
```

I know I have to Malloc, but I'm not sure what. Do I have to Malloc the structure and the arrays inside of it? I don't know how I'd Malloc the entire struct as I won't know how big it will be until I know x, so I can't use size-of? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have multiple flexible array members in a C structure, so you'll have to go the route of allocating each member's array independently:

```
typedef struct
{
    int *a, *b; 
    char *c, *d; 
    char (*string)[100];     
} agentInfo;

int initStruct(agentInfo *ai, int x)
{
    ai->a = malloc(x * sizeof(int));
    ai->b = malloc(x * sizeof(int));
    ai->c = malloc(x);
    ai->d = malloc(x);
    ai->string = malloc(100 * x);
    return 0;
}
```

You'd use it something like:

```
agentInfo ai;
initStruct(&ai, 12);
```

Comment: @Potatoswatter, no, there are 100 strings and they're `x` long: `char string[100][x]` from OP's post.

Comment: Correct. It doesn't fit the pattern in the rest of the `struct` so OP may be wrong. Anyway, good thing I upvoted.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, no. There are 100 strings `x` long.  See OP's post `char string[100][x]`.

Comment: Thanks. It's meant to be x strings with a length of 100, my mistake.

Comment: Ok, that loop will need to be different then.

Comment: @user2655377 - fixed to be a pointer to an array of 100-length strings.